# Recurrence Relation on Ternary Sequences

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following homework assignment:

> Let $s_n$ be the number of ternary sequences of length n, such that the sub-sequences 00, 01, 10, and 11 never occur.
> Prove that $s_n = s_{n-1} + 2s_{n-2}$ for $ n \ge 3$ with $s_1 = 3$ and $s_2 = 5$
>
> Then find a direct formula for $s_n$.

So I found the direct formula using the second-order homogeneous linear difference equation and got  $s_n = - {\frac{1}{3}}(-1)^n + {\frac{4}{3}}(2)^n $
as my solution for the second part. I'm not quite sure how to go about proving the recurrence relation for this.

Comment: Let $X_n$ be the collection of ternary sequences of length $n$ satisfying given constraint. $X_n$ is a disjoint union of 3 subsets:
$$\{ 02.x : x \in X_{n-2} \}
\;\sqcup\; \{ 12.x : x \in X_{n-2} \} \;\sqcup\; X_n = \{ 2.y : y \in X_{n-1} \}$$
where $.$ stands for concatenation of sequences.